# Basic conversion of sequence of images to avi with avconv

Tags: ubuntu, video-conversion, libav

I'm trying to convert sequnce of images to small avi. Each image should be shown 2 seconds.

I'm using this basic command

```
sudo avconv -r 0.5 -i test%05d.jpg  out.avi
```

I get the output, but it shows only the first image for the entire length of the movie (which is as expected = number of images * 2 sec)

Images are named as

```
test00000.jpg
test00001.jpg
test00002.jpg
test00003.jpg
etc.
```

Classical question: What am I doing wrong? Ubuntu, fresh install of avconv.

The output:

```
sudo avconv -r 0.5  -i test%05d.jpg  out.avi
avconv version 9.18-6:9.18-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 16 2015 13:19:10 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
Input #0, image2, from 'test%05d.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.68, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 230x230 [PAR 72:72 DAR 1:1], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn
File 'out.avi' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, avi, to 'out.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf54.20.4
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 230x230 [PAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 0.50 tbn, 0.50 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg -> mpeg4)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
frame=   17 fps=  0 q=2.0 Lsize=      69kB time=34.00 bitrate=  16.6kbits/s
video:63kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 9.579780%
```

Comment: Please show the full, uncut command line output. Note that [`avconv` has nothing to do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/what-are-the-differences-and-similarities-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv) with the FFmpeg project or command-line program. Make sure that when you paste the log, you format it as code in the editor. You can do that by selecting it and hitting `Ctrl-K`.

Comment: This is full command. Not cutted.
My question is about avconv, not FFmpeg.
https://libav.org/avconv.html

Comment: Please show the full **output**, not just the command. It may be helpful in troubleshooting the issue. (You tagged your question with `ffmpeg`, hence my comment.)

Comment: Seems like it doesn't even recognize other images, because it only reports the first one with a short duration. Can you download a recent version of ffmpeg (e.g. from [here](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/)) and try it with that instead?

Comment: Just a quick FYI for future people with this problem. If you're experimenting with the avconf parameters, you can end up copying the first jpeg to all the others. Always experiment with a copy of the data, not the real thing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in avconv.
Actually it was an "User error. Replace user"

All jpg images were the same (what I didn't know). So when joined into avi the "only first image has been shown". But in reality the avi showed all images. 
But as they were all the same it looked like only the first in being shown.

For me the question can be deleted :(

Comment: Hi Alexander, if there a no answers on a question you can delete it on your own.